# textbox width issue display on Iphones

Tags: iphone, responsive-design, textbox, width

I’m a new member of this forum and this is my first post.

I been struggling for weeks with a responsive login of my private website.

I have coded the login page in a way that it will adjust to any mobile width. I have had a little success in displaying the login page and display correctly in many devices, except Iphone devices.

I have noticed that the textboxes for username and password will continue to the right as if it had a higher width. I mean it will fall out of its parent div.

I have created an image with the devices I have mainly focused and showing the issue as well for iphones.

[Click here to see the image.](http://postimg.org/image/6jrtx4gjd/full/)

maybe I’m missing a specific characteristic that iphones has and I need to put it my css codes.

any idea?

Comment: iphones are generally 320px in width. does that help?

Comment: yea I am aware of that, since i'm targeting many devices in order to avoid several media queries changing widths, I just use percentage.

Comment: that's a lazy mistake. you only need like 3 media queries, maybe 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix my own issue. After changing all css properties and playing around like i had no idea what i was doing. The simple solution was to reduce the width of textbox by 5%, just for iphones lol. I can't believe that took me so long to figure out. that's why i love coding.